# Does "Profile Views" include me looking at my own profile?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, views

According to the counter, 93 people have looked at my profile:

> [image: Screensot]

Does this include me looking at my own profile, or does it only count other people who actually looked at my profile ?  It doesn't increment when I go to my profile page, so I assume it's the latter ?

Comment: I would assume it counts unique visitors rather than number of visits.

Comment: I often use my profile to navigate to/from meta, and in meta my views are 49, so I'd say an absolute certain, definite, at least not all the time. If that leaves the difference between never, and once, or very occasionally, I think your answer is generally No.

Comment: I would hope not. There is an [MSE feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12766/190066) marked completed back in 2009.